# Android Maps close routes

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

I need direction of how to start or what to look for (new to this).
Developing for Android Google maps, I have 2 routes drawn on map.

I want to know if ANY point on one route is close to ANY point on the other (close means up to 5km). How do I calculate this? Any example for this?